# Mixing Dura Ace 9000 drivetrain with ultegra?

Tags: drivetrain, groupsets

I'd like to mix the DA9K drivetrain (chain, chainrings, front and rear mech, excluding the cassette) with my current ultegra 6800 setup. I dislike the DA shifters, but I'm ready to upgrade my shifting and braking cables if need be (suggestions welcome).

Is this going to work?

Answer (score 2):

I believe Shimano uses the same cable pull ratio for all 11 speed groups, so 11 speed DA derailleurs and 11 speed Ultegra shifters should work just fine.